# Why does this only increment the score the first time it is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Reproduction steps:**

1. Open http://playclassicsnake.com/play
2. Click the left, up or down arrow key to make the snake (green squares) move
3. Direct the snake over the food (red circle)
4. Total Score goes from 0 to 10
5. Direct the snake over the food again
6. Total Score is still 10

**Expected behavior:**

Score should be incremented by 10 each time the snake's head hits the food.

**Relevant Javascript:**

```
function StatHandler ( totalScoreSelector, fruitEatenSelector )
{
    this.scoreElem = $(totalScoreSelector);
    this.fruitEeatenElem = $(fruitEatenSelector);

    this.incrementScore = function ( incAmount )
    {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Play/IncrementScore?amount=" + incAmount,
            success: function (newScore)
            {
                that.scoreElem.text(newScore);
                console.log(newScore); // TEST
            },
            error: function ( ) 
            {
                alert("error occured!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
        if (game.food.pos.x == newHeadX && game.food.pos.y == newHeadY) // if new head hit food
        {
            this.links.push(new game.elementOnGrid(game.board.rect(oldTailX * game.blockWidth, oldTailY * game.blockWidth, game.blockWidth, game.blockWidth).attr('fill', '#19FF19'),
                            oldTailX,
                            oldTailY
                            ));       // fill space left by trail before it was translated
            // i.e. lengthen the snake
            game.coords[oldTailX][oldTailY] = true; // update coordinate list
            game.stats.incrementScore(10);
            game.placeFood(); // replace food
        }
```

---

**Relevant C#:**

```
public class PlayController : Controller
{

    private ushort score;

    // GET: Play
    public ActionResult Index ( )
    {
        ResetScore();
        return View ( );
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ushort IncrementScore ( ushort amount )
    {
        score += amount;
        return score;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void ResetScore ( )
    {
        score = 0;
    }
}
```

Any ideas about what is going on?

Comment: `score` is initialized in you controller each time you call the `IncrementScore()` method (with a value of zero). `return score;` will only ever return the value of `amount`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke So should I put the score in sessions storage?

Comment: That's one option. You need to persist it somewhere :) Of course you could just do the calculation on the client if your not wanting to persist the value permanently (e.g. to be able to resume the game later)

Comment: When did john skeet play and got so much score.. Just kidding.. :)